# sql query with priorities on attributes

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

hi there
imagine I have a table like this

```
Id | Name       | City
1  | Tom york   | xx
2  | Jim york   | xy
3  | tony       | new York
4  | Sam york   | xz
```

and I would like to search records with name like '%york%' or city like '%york%' 
BUT i want to give more priority to name, so my rresult would be something like:

```
Id | Name       | City
1  | Tom york   | xx
2  | Jim york   | xy
4  | Sam york   | xz
3  | tony       | new York
```

that is, first the records where name like '%york%' and then the records where city like '%york%'

whats the best way to build this query? can I do it in a single query?
answers in sql or linq to sql would be great

tks

Comment: Is '%a%' the only search string you need to use, or might you use a different letter, or more than one char for the match?

Comment: yeah, this was only an eample, in reality the table would have real names or cities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that what you mean by "but I want to give more priority to name" is that you want to get the entities with `"a"` in `Name` first, and then the other ones (with `"a"` in `City`). The respective Linq-to-SQL query would be:

```
Entities
.Where(e => e.Name.Contains("a") || e.City.Contains("a"))
.OrderByDescending(e => e.Name.Contains("a"));
```

Comment: tks dan, only one thing, added descending to order by, but that seems to do the trick, tks

Comment: @martin - You are right, I corrected, it should have been OrderByDescending instead of OrderBy there.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from (
    select Id, Name, City, 1 as Rank
    from MyTable
    where Name like '%a%' 
    union all
    select Id, Name, City, 2 as Rank
    from MyTable
    where City like '%a%'
) a
order by Rank
```

Answer (score 3):

An SQL version of Dan Dumitru's solution would be:

```
SELECT Id, Name, City
FROM   cities
WHERE Name LIKE 'b%'
   OR City LIKE 'b%'
ORDER BY
   Name LIKE 'b%' DESC
```

With some example data:

```
Id | Name | City
1  | aa   | bb
2  | bb   | aa
```

This gives:

```
Id  Name    City
2   bb      aa
1   aa      bb
```

Whereas

```
SELECT Id, Name, City
FROM   cities
WHERE Name LIKE 'b%' 
   OR City LIKE 'b%'
ORDER BY
    Name, City
```

Gives the incorrect:

```
Id  Name  City
1   aa    bb
2   bb    aa
```

That's because in the first we sorted by which field matched, but in the second we sorted by field *values*.